# Why '==' is fast than manually traversal of two strings comparison in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, time-complexity

I try to solve the problem [28. Implement Str](https://leetcode-cn.com/problems/implement-strstr/) on LeetCode.

However, I have some questions about the time complexity of the two versions of the implemented codes.

```py
# Version 1
class Solution:
    def strStr(self, haystack, needle):
        
        len_h = len(haystack)
        len_n = len(needle)
        if not needle:
            return 0
        if len_n > len_h:
            return -1

        i = 0
        while i<len_h :
            found = True
            if haystack[i] == needle[0]:
                for j in range(len_n):
                    if i+j >= len_h or haystack[i+j] != needle[j]:
                        found = False
                        break
                if found:
                    return i

            i += 1
        
        return -1
```

In this version, I try to find the needle substring in the haystack using the **double loops**.

I think the time complexity of the code is **O(mn)** where **m** is the length of the haystack and **n** is the length of the needle.

Unfortunately, the code cannot pass the tests due to **the time exceeding**.

Then, I try to optimize my code and get version 2 of the code.

```py
# Version 2
class Solution:
    def strStr(self, haystack, needle):
        len_h = len(haystack)
        len_n = len(needle)
        if not needle:
            return 0
        if len_n > len_h:
            return -1

        i = 0
        while i<len_h :
            found = True
            if haystack[i] == needle[0]:
                if haystack[i:i+len_n] == needle:
                    return i
                
            i += 1
        
        return -1
```

I compare the needle and the substring of the haystack using **string-slice** and **'=='** instead of the manual comparison. Then, the code passes the tests.

Now, I have some questions:

1. What is the time complexity of the string slice?
2. What is the time complexity of the check operation (==) between two strings?
3. Why version 2 is fast than version 1 if the time complexity of the check operation is O(n)?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Slice and equality comparison on strings is generally done in linear time. However, using built-in mechanisms is implemented natively, so `a == b` is *way* faster than implementing the same built-in logic with Python. That’s just how Python works.

Answer (score 1):

`str.__eq__(self, other)` (that is, equality for strings) is implemented in C and is lightning fast (as fast as any other language once it starts).

Your Python-implemented character-wise string comparison is slow for two reasons.  First, the looping logic is implemented in Python, and Python loops are never very fast.  Second, when you say `needle[j]` that is slicing one string to construct another one.  That by itself is slow, and you do it in a nested loop, so the overall runtime will be disastrous.  You end up calling `str.__eq__` once per character, and every time it's called it has to check the length of the strings on each side (it does not know you just sliced a single character).

Comment: Thank you @John, I do not know that `needle[j]` is also the slice operation. I think the `str` object can be index like `list` and I will note this in the future.

Comment: @Zhangrong.Huang: Yes, indexing a list gives you one element of that list.  Indexing a string gives you a string.  This is different to a lot of programming languages where indexing a string gives you a single character as a distinct type.